# 18.04 logwatch version is mismatched to postfix-policyd-spf-python -- how to escalate?

Tags: 18.04, lts, postfix, logwatch

**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** provides the versions shown below of *logwatch*, *postfix*, and *postfix-policyd-spf-python*. This particular release of *logwatch* is old, and does not correctly process some of the messages produced by *postfix-policyd-spf-python*. As a result, reports from *logwatch* are noisy with false alerts. The current release of *logwatch* from upstream (7.5.2) contains code which handles the messages involved.

A simple workaround is to extract the *.../scripts/services/postfix* file and install it under */etc/logwatch*, but the reason for using a package manager is precisely to avoid having to make this kind of intervention.

How should this version incompatibility best be escalated to the Ubuntu LTS maintenance (or release engineering) team?

```
$ apt list -a postfix logwatch postfix-policyd-spf-python
Listing... Done
logwatch/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 7.4.3+git20161207-2ubuntu1.1 all [installed]
logwatch/bionic,bionic 7.4.3+git20161207-2ubuntu1 all

postfix/bionic-updates,now 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
postfix/bionic 3.3.0-1 amd64

postfix-policyd-spf-python/bionic,bionic,now 2.0.2-1 all [installed]

$
```

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Are all of the app's mentioned installed from standard Ubuntu repositories, from 3.part PPA's or other means ?

Comment: System is up to date. I run those utilities daily on all my Ubuntu instances. All of the apps mentioned are installed from standard Ubuntu repositories. The problem is that the releases of *postfix-policyd-spf-python* and *logwatch* selected for inclusion are not well matched, as the former produces messages which the latter does not handle correctly.